# Reorganizing Data in a data table

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-management

I have data that is formatted this way when I pull it for the web data base.

| site | date | time | parameter_code | remark_code | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 01-01-2020 | 15:10 | 00010 | NA | 16.6 |
| 001 | 01-01-2020 | 15:10 | 00095 | NA | 521.0 |
| 001 | 01-01-2020 | 15:10 | 00300 | NA | 5.6 |
| 001 | 01-01-2020 | 15:10 | 34475 | < | 1.0 |
| 001 | 03-30-2020 | 09:45 | 00010 | NA | 18.0 |
| 001 | 03-30-2020 | 09:45 | 00095 | NA | 546.0 |
| 001 | 03-30-2020 | 09:45 | 00300 | NA | 3.7 |
| 001 | 03-30-2020 | 09:45 | 34475 | NA | 2.3 |

I want to format it as shown below.
I know that I need to combine the columns of Remark_code and Result first, but I'm not sure how to parse out the Parameter_code column into individual columns with the Result filling in the "body" of the table.

| site | date | time | 00010 | 00095 | 00300 | 34475 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 01-01-2020 | 15:10 | 16.6 | 521.0 | 5.6 | <1.0 |
| 001 | 03-30-2020 | 15:10 | 18.0 | 546.0 | 3.7 | 2.3 |

I don't necessarily need all of the code on how to do this, but just direction on what functions to use. I've been struggling with this since I'm not even sure what key words to look up or what this type of transformation(?) this would be called. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are looking to "reshape from long to wide." Base R has the `reshape` function.  Another popular option is `tidyr::pivot_wider`.  Note that the "wide" format is popular in excel tables, while most R users prefer their datasets in "long" format (like you already have).  Hadley's paper on [Tidy Data](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) explains why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider` after `unite`ing the columns 'REMARK_CODE' and 'RESULT'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  unite(RESULT, REMARK_CODE, RESULT, sep="", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = PARAMETER_CODE, values_from = RESULT)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#   SITE  DATE      TIME  `10`  `95`  `300` `34475`   
#   <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
# 1 001   1/1/2020  15:10 16.6  521   5.6   <1     
#   2 001   3/30/2020 9:45  18    546   3.7   2.3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SITE = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", 
"001", "001"), DATE = c("1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", 
"3/30/2020", "3/30/2020", "3/30/2020", "3/30/2020"), TIME = c("15:10", 
"15:10", "15:10", "15:10", "9:45", "9:45", "9:45", "9:45"), PARAMETER_CODE = c(10L, 
95L, 300L, 34475L, 10L, 95L, 300L, 34475L), REMARK_CODE = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "<", NA, NA, NA, NA), RESULT = c(16.6, 521, 5.6, 1, 18, 
546, 3.7, 2.3)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% mutate(RESULT=ifelse(is.na(REMARK_CODE),paste0('',RESULT),
                            paste0(REMARK_CODE,RESULT))) %>%
  select(-REMARK_CODE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = PARAMETER_CODE,values_from=RESULT)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  SITE  DATE      TIME  `10`  `95`  `300` `34475`
  <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 001   1/1/2020  15:10 16.6  521   5.6   <1     
2 001   3/30/2020 9:45  18    546   3.7   2.3
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(SITE = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", 
"001", "001"), DATE = c("1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", 
"3/30/2020", "3/30/2020", "3/30/2020", "3/30/2020"), TIME = c("15:10", 
"15:10", "15:10", "15:10", "9:45", "9:45", "9:45", "9:45"), PARAMETER_CODE = c(10L, 
95L, 300L, 34475L, 10L, 95L, 300L, 34475L), REMARK_CODE = c(NA, 
NA, NA, "<", NA, NA, NA, NA), RESULT = c(16.6, 521, 5.6, 1, 18, 
546, 3.7, 2.3)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```